# Android Manifest conflict causing sms permission to not work

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm having this issue where the sms permission won't work when sending a text message while having the following piece of code in android manifest.

```
   <activity android:name=".engine.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If I were to replace this code with this:

```
 <activity
                android:name=".SendSmsActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Sms starts working. I also tried adding the second code like this under the code that's conflicting:

```
 <activity android:name=".ui.SendSmsActivity">

        </activity>
```

But that doesn't work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

Android Manifeset

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android_auto">


        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />


        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />


        <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">



            <activity android:name=".engine.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>


  <activity android:name=".ui.SendSmsActivity">

            </activity>


            <activity android:name=".ui.MapsActivity1">

            </activity>

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application" android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCMFYfJ6aOuxJk3W0vmhF6Nou3TP_qIU6c" />

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <!--
         Main music service, provides media browsing and media playback services to
                 consumers through MediaBrowserService and MediaSession. Consumers connect to it through
                 MediaBrowser (for browsing) and MediaController (for playback control)
                -->
            <service android:name=".MyMusicService" android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
            <service android:name=".MyMessagingService" />

            <receiver android:name=".MessageReadReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.zachboone.myapplication.ACTION_MESSAGE_READ" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
            <receiver android:name=".MessageReplyReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.zachboone.myapplication.ACTION_MESSAGE_REPLY" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

        </application>




    </manifest>
```

SendSmsActivity.java

```
package aaa_android_auto.ui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android_auto.R;


public class SendSmsActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textPhoneNo;
    EditText textSMS;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "the sms permission won't work" means.

Comment: TO send an sms you have to declare the permission in your manifest like this:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

If you just open the phone's sms messanger, declaring an intent, you may avoid declaring it.

However, your question is unclear. Please provide the java code where you try to send an sms.

Comment: I have the sms permission the android manifest, but the code that has .engine.MainActivity is hindering it from executing. If I removed that code then the sms text messaging works, but if it stays there then it stops the sms functionality. I added SendSmsActivity above, but I feel the issue lies in the android manifest since the code works when the android manifest has the mentioned code replaced. I can't get all the code to play nicely together in android manifest